# Body scroll moves in an unexpected way

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

Here is the video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8pzl53p_TQ

The full source code is here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      background-color: darkblue;
      height: 150vh;
    }

    #container {
      margin: 100px 0 0 100px;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    .item {
      width: 300px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: red;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      flex-shrink: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
</div>
<script>

  setInterval(() => {
    appendNewItem();
  }, 500);

  function appendNewItem() {
    const containerDom = document.getElementById('container');
    const appendDom = document.createElement('div');
    const firstChild = containerDom.children[0];
    appendDom.className = 'item';
    containerDom.insertBefore(appendDom, firstChild);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If the body scroll is only slightly lowered so that the top of the list is invisible, the body scroll moves in an unexpected direction according to the list animation.

I don't know why this is happening. I don't know the cause of this bug, and I don't know how to fix it. please reply.

Comment: do you mean before you didn't have the body scroll ? but after divs being appended it appears ?

Comment: Before the div is created and the list is filled, the body scroll moves in an unexpected direction as in the video even if the body scroll is lowered a little.

Comment: okkay I got t check my answer it'll do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe it's a bug for browser, or it's not a bug because browser try to scroll the view to note the user that someting is inserted.

There is a hack for this 'bug' running well on chrome and firefox:

```js
const temp = document.documentElement.scrollTop; // new line
containerDom.insertBefore(appendDom, firstChild);
document.documentElement.scrollTop = temp; // new line
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-shape-1snb8?file=/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

okkay you need `overflow-y: scroll ;`    in your container , and since the item is just a div you don't need to use `display : flex;`

```
  #container {
      margin: 100px 0 0 100px;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      overflow-y: scroll;//this modification
      
      /* not necessary
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center; */

      background-color: yellow;
    }
    .item {
      width: 100%;//itèll take what ever its parents width value 
      height: 40px;
      background-color: red;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: Still having problems

Comment: Do you have any idea how it works in Google Chrome too?

Comment: I tried chrome and its working just fine , you might wanna close your text editor and re open it also close chrome or what ever browser you're using

Comment: Still, the problem occurs. But thank you very much for your help.

Comment: are you sure you have tried ```overflow-y: scroll; ``` in your scroll

Comment: btw since your items are just dvs you don't need to use flex on container , this will do ```#container {
      padding: 10px;
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      background-color: yellow;
    } ```

Comment: If you look at the list of links https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xBFYUQzL04 there is a scroll bar. I added "overflow-y: hidden;". Still, the problem occurs.

Comment: I fixed the question. The way you gave me.

Comment: solved okkay amazing , mark the question as answer thank you

Comment: Thank you very much. However, the source code modified according to your answer won't work.